# Editing / installing a registry file (.reg) based on processor architecture

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, x86-64, registrykey

i have created a registry file which installs a key for **URL Alert Protocol**, so that when user click on some relevant link in our web app in any browser, that link will be opened in **Internet Explorer**.
This works pretty well.
Problem is, customer requirement is to install the **registry key for IE under 32 bit**. Means, whatever the user's processor architecture is (x86, x64), registry must be installed to **use IE under 32 bit**. Now i am unable to set the **conditional variable** which set the path for **Program Files** (in 32 bit) or **Program Files (x86)** (in 64bit) for that purpose.
 Any help? 
below is the registry key entry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IEFrmOB]
@="\"URL:Alert Protocol\""
"URL Protocol"="\"\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IEFrmOB\DefaultIcon]
@="\"iexplore.exe,1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IEFrmOB\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IEFrmOB\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IEFrmOB\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /v /k set \"myvar=%1\" & set myvar=!myvar:IEFrmOB:=! & start \"\" /B \"!ProgramFiles!\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" !myvar! & exit"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you used the cmd to start the IE process from code below:

```
"!ProgramFiles!\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe
```

If we used bat command to start the 32bit IE, I suggest that you could add the architecture judgement command in the cmd command, as the below :
[image]

```
set myvar="123"
set IEfolder=""
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (set IEfolder="%PROGRAMFILES%") else (set 
IEfolder="%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%") 
set IEfolder=%IEfolder:~1,-1%\Internet Explorer
echo %IEfolder%
start "%IEfolder%" iexplore.exe www.bing.com
```

and you could add above judgement code into registry and test it. The code as below:

```
@="cmd /v /k set \"myvar=%1\" & set myvar=!myvar:IEFrmOB:=! & IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (set IEfolder="PROGRAMFILES") else (set IEfolder="PROGRAMFILES(X86)") &start \"\" /B \"%IEfolder%\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" !myvar! & exit"
```

But I am not sure when we call x86 IE, Windows OS only starts the 32 bit IE if your OS is 64 bit. Because IE11 could be started with 2 process(32 bit and 64 bit) at the same time .
If above method didn't work, you could check IE settings to modify IE process :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b34d705-ba27-4359-a34b-e1ff766878ea/force-ie-11-to-open-in-32-bit-mode?forum=win10itprogeneral